# Python sklearn dcg_score wrong (?) output

Tags: python, scikit-learn

I am trying to replicate the wikipedia example for discounted cumulative gain. I was able to replicate with excel but having different result on python.

I used the instructions here: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/normalized-discounted-cumulative-gain-multilabel-ranking-metrics-ml/

My code:

```
# import required package
from sklearn.metrics import ndcg_score, dcg_score
import numpy as np

# Relevance scores in Ideal order
true_relevance = np.asarray([[3, 3, 2, 2, 1, 0]])

# Relevance scores in output order
relevance_score = np.asarray([[3, 2, 3, 0, 1, 2]])

# DCG score
dcg = dcg_score(true_relevance, relevance_score)
print("DCG score : ", dcg)

# IDCG score
idcg = dcg_score(true_relevance, true_relevance)
print("IDCG score : ", idcg)

# Normalized DCG score
ndcg = dcg / idcg
print("nDCG score : ", ndcg)
```

The output:

```
DCG score :  6.57260640248932 #<- should be 6.861
IDCG score :  7.140995184095699 #<- this is OK
nDCG score :  0.9204048221636831 #<- should be 0.961
```

Any ideas what's wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Simply speaking, the y_true works as the gain, the y_predictes decides the order. y_true can be any order. y_true will be sorted by y_score. check this example:

```
y_true = np.asarray([[2, 0, 4]])
y_score = np.asarray([[-33212424, -2, -1]])
pred_dcg = dcg_score(y_true, y_score)
ideal_dcg = dcg_score(y_true, y_true)
print(pred_dcg, ideal_dcg)
```

For pred_dcg, after sorting by y_score (desc order, bigger score, higher position), we get:

```
[4,0,2]
```

where discounts are:

```
[log_2(2), log_2(3), log_2(4)] = [1, xx, 0.5]
```

so the dcg score will be: 3

Comment: Thanks. Don't think I follow. Could you explain with this list [3, 2, 3, 0, 1, 2]

Comment: [3, 2, 3, 0, 1, 2] only contribute the order of the y_true sequence, do not contribute any value/score for computing DCG score.

Answer (score 0):

index [1,2,3,4,5,6] -> score: [6,5,4,3,2,1]

Code:

```
from sklearn.metrics import dcg_score
y_true = [[3, 2, 3, 0, 1, 2]]
y_score = [[6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1]]
dcg = dcg_score(y_true, y_score)
print("DCG score : ", dcg)
```

Output:

```
DCG score :  6.861126688593501
```